# C++ "list iterator not dereferenceable" error

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2012, iterator

I am trying to write code that will alphabetize strings in a linked list. Here is what I have written:

```
void main() {
list<string> myList;
list<string>::iterator pos;

string newData;
myList.push_back("Anna");

pos = myList.begin();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cin >> newData;
    while(newData > *pos)
        pos++;

    myList.insert(pos, newData);
}

system("pause");
}
```

This code compiles fine but I get an error that the list iterator is not dereferenceable when I run it.

I am very new with linked lists and iterators so I really don't know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In addition to the answers, it wouldn't hurt to switch `pos++` to the less wasteful `++pos`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this cycle:

```
while(newData > *pos)
    pos++;
```

Depending on your input, you might keep increasing `pos` until you reach the end of the list.  At that point, dereferencing it when checking the condition of your `while` loop causes **Undefined Behavior**.

To fix your program, rewrite your cycle as follows:

```
while ((pos != myList.end()) && (newData > *pos))
{
    pos++;
}
```

P.S.: Also notice, that you most likely want to move the `pos = myList.begin();` statement inside the `for` loop, if your intention is to insert the items in inverse lexicographic order (as it seems to be).

Comment: ... you also have to move the `pos = myList.begin();` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @us2012: Most likely that's what the OP would want, indeed (although leaving it there won't cause UB). But I'll add this to my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(newData > *pos)
    pos++;
```

When `pos++`, it may points to `list::end()` and dereference it `*pos` is **undefined behavior.**

Your list is not sorted anyway, could just list::push_back

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cin >> newData;
    myList.push_back(newData);
}
```

Then sort it later:

```
  myList.sort();
```

Comment: It seems that OP want to maintain a sorted list.

Comment: His list order depends on input

Answer (score 0):

While doing `pos++`, you may reach the end of the list, i.e. `pos == myList.end()`.

At that point, further `*pos` or `pos++` is illegal.

The loop logic need to be revise to avoid such illegal instructions.